# Regexp solution for list

Tags: regex, tcl

I am not able to figure it following regexp,
Script1:

```
set name_list {{Avg Speed} {Total Time(hr) }}
set lines {{Avg Speed|0.000} {Total Time(hr)|NA} }

set line_number 0
foreach line $lines {
    incr line_number

    foreach name $name_list {
        puts "flag1: $name"
        if { [regexp "^$name\\|(.+)$" $line matchVar value ] } {
            puts "flag4: $value"
            set rval($name) $value
            set rval($name,line) $line_number
        }
    }
}
```

The output is something like:
Output1:

```
    flag1: Avg Speed
    flag4: 0.000
    flag1: Total Time(hr) 
    flag1: Avg Speed
    flag1: Total Time(hr)
```

If i change first 2 lines like:
Script2(Modified):

```
set name_list {{Avg Speed} {Total Time}}
set lines {{Avg Speed|0.000} {Total Time|NA} }
```

I am getting something like this:
Output2 (Want output like this-Actual output)

```
   flag1: Avg Speed
   flag4: 0.000
   flag1: Total Time
   flag1: Avg Speed
   flag1: Total Time
   flag4: NA
```

So, how should i modify my regexp such that I get I get "(hr)" to be printed at output1 flag4 in first script?

```
regexp "^$name\\|(.+)$" $line matchVar value
```

What is the purpose of matchVar exactly, beacuse here it is matching "0.000 & NA", but how?

Comment: In the second element of name_list, you need to escape the parentheses and delete the space at the end.

Comment: The third argument of `regexp` (`matchVar`) gets the value of the whole match. The following arguments are names of variables that get the values of captured groups (the parts that match the stuff in parentheses).

Comment: In the name list, there's a space after "total time(na)" but there's not a space in the lines list before the pipe symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem: you're using a regular expression where a simple string comparison is appropriate:

```
set name_list {{Avg Speed} {Total Time(hr)}}      ;# <- note that I've shaved off space
set lines {{Avg Speed|0.000} {Total Time(hr)|NA}}

set line_number 0
foreach line $lines {
    incr line_number

    foreach name $name_list {
        puts "flag1: $name"
        lassign [split $line |] _name value
        if {$_name eq $name} {
            puts "flag4: $value"
            set rval($name) $value
            set rval($name,line) $line_number
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Thank you for alternate solution, It is informative... (y). As you said, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `matchVar` is to capture the entire substring that is matched by the RE; when you anchor the RE at both ends, it is the same as the input string (if the RE matches at all) and can probably be ignored. It's much more relevant when your RE is unanchored or only anchored on one side, when the overall matched (sub)string provides you with useful information.

Your real problem though is that the string you are injecting into the RE to search for has itself got RE metacharacters in it; the `(hr)` is being treated as a sub-RE that happens to match `hr` and presents it as one of the submatched portions that `regexp` can report on. To fix this, we need to add backslashes to the RE metacharacters before substitution. We can do that with `regsub -all` as the RE sub-language guarantees that all metacharacters are not alphanumeric “word” characters, and can be quoted safely by putting a backslash in front of them.

```
# ...
foreach name $name_list {
    puts "flag1: $name"
    # Replace all non-word characters with their backslashed form
    regsub -all {\W} $name {\\&} REname
    if { [regexp "^$REname\\|(.+)$" $line matchVar value ] } {
        # ...
```